# No known package when getting value for resource number 0x020a0057

Tags: android, webview, datepicker

I just updated my app to API level 25 in an attempt to get a WebView displayed `datetime-local` to use the proper picker.  But now as soon as I tap on the element in the WebView my app crashes, with the following messages in logcat:

```
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x020a0057
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x20a0057
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:463)
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.ui.picker.DateTimePickerDialog.<init>(DateTimePickerDialog.java:78)
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.ui.picker.InputDialogContainer.showPickerDialog(InputDialogContainer.java:221)
01-01 16:17:22.578 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.ui.picker.InputDialogContainer.showPickerDialog(InputDialogContainer.java:102)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.input.DateTimeChooserAndroid.createDateTimeChooser(DateTimeChooserAndroid.java:1188)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
01-01 16:17:22.579 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
01-01 16:17:22.581 10219-10219/com.example.test548 A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(236)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
01-01 16:17:22.695 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
01-01 16:17:22.695 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
01-01 16:17:22.695 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/google-breakpad: 1.0.19
01-01 16:17:22.695 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/google-breakpad: 20
01-01 16:17:22.695 10219-10219/com.example.test548 W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
01-01 16:17:22.695 10219-10219/com.example.test548 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10219 (le.test548)
```

None of the packages in the call stack are my code. What am I doing wrong?

How can I set string resource "0x20a0057" so the crash won't happen?

Comment: did you manage to get rid of the exception?